# RE2/Perl RegEx, selecting all rows without any of multiple words

Tags: regex, regex-negation, re2

I'm having difficulties with the negative lookahead not being available RE2.
With normal regex I would just do something like this:

```regex
^(?!text|someText|.*cont).*
```

To exclude rows beginning with "text", "someText" and containing "cont". Unfortunately the negative lookahead is not available with RE2.

How can we solve this?

Answer (score -1):

You could handle the negative lookahead conditions by using a positive match, and then expecting the negation of that.  For example:

```
$input = "text is good";
if ($input !~ m/^(text|someText).*$/ && $input !~ m/^.*cont.*$/) {
    print "MATCH";
}
else {
    print "NO MATCH";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it has to be done with a single regex string, is that possible as well?

Comment: Yes, it is _possible_, but I think the pattern might look very ugly, even bufugly.  What is wrong with the suggestion I gave to you?

Comment: It is used as a configuration parameter :(